# нужно открыть ссылку на 1 ый клуб после поиска по названию ,

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup

вообщем с сайта strava нужно перейти на первый найденный клуб, но не каждый клуб является открытым желательно это сделать с помощью find . суть в том что перейти не в каждый клуб можно т.к. он закрытый. нужен if..

```
  hover = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-nav"]/ul[1]/li[3]/a')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(hover).perform()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
button=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-nav"]/ul[1]/li[3]/ul/li[4]/a')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
club_name=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]')
club_name.send_keys('Ryazan')
time.sleep(3)
time.sleep(3)
find=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div/input[7]').click()
ht=browser.current_url
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
soup.html.head.title
```

[image: сайт страницы]

Comment: нужно именно для любого клуба

Comment: У вас какой-то дико странный код в примере. Зачем в конце строки использование BS? Зачем вы несколько раз меняете период ожидания? Зачем вы скроллите страницу - selenium и без этого будет прекрасно работать?